# volley return null response when status code is 400

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm trying to post data to API in android which it's successful in postman with this body raw:

```
{
    "phonenumber": "12345",
    "username": "test",
    "password": "1234",
    "roles": 1
}
```

The response in successful is:

```
{
    "message": "Registered successfully!"
}
```

And the response in error is:

```
{
    "message": "Failed! this user already registered!"
}
```

So in android, I tried first the retrofit library and the post works perfectly if the user that I tried to register does not exist and I get the response correct
but if the user exist so the response return null 400 status code

So I tried to do it using volley in order to solve the problem but got the same result
This is my code:

```
private void userSignUp(){

        //defining a progress dialog to show while signing up
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Signing Up...");
        progressDialog.show();

        String phonenumber = editTextPhonenumber.getText().toString().trim();
        String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        // url to post our data
        String url = "http://xxxx/api/auth/signup";

        // creating a new variable for our request queue
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SignUpActivity.this);

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            //input your API parameters
            object.put("phonenumber", phonenumber);
            object.put("username", username);
            object.put("password", password);
            object.put("roles", 1);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, object,
                new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "String Response : "+ response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "String Response : "+ error.networkResponse.statusCode + "\nResponse Data " + error.networkResponse.data
                        + "\nCause " + error.getCause()
                        + "\nmessage" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }){
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }
        };

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

And this is the retrofit version:

```
private void userSignUp(){

        //defining a progress dialog to show while signing up
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Signing Up...");
        progressDialog.show();

        String phonenumber = editTextPhonenumber.getText().toString().trim();
        String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        //building retrofit object
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        //Defining retrofit api service
        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

        //Defining the user object as we need to pass it with the call
        User user = new User(phonenumber, username, password, 1);

        //defining the call
        Call<Result> call = service.createUser(user);

        //calling the api
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
                //hiding progress dialog
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "onResponse: " + response.body() + "    " + response.errorBody());
                }


                //displaying the message from the response as toast
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //if there is no error
                if (response.body().getMessage() == "User was registered successfully!") {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "response.body().getMessage()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //starting profile activity
                    finish();
                    SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                }
                else {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

With it's apiservice:

```
public interface APIService {
    //The register call
    @POST("auth/signup")
    Call<Result> createUser(@Body User user);
}
```

Request pojo:

```
public class User {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("phonenumber")
    private String phonenumber;

    @SerializedName("username")
    private String username;

    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;

    @SerializedName("roles")
    private int roles;

    public User(String phonenumber, String username, String password, int roles) {
        this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public User(int id, String phonenumber, String username, int roles){
        this.id = id;
        this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
        this.username = username;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public User(int id, String phonenumber, String username, String password, int roles) {
        this.id = id;
        this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getPhonenumber() {
        return phonenumber;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

    public int getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
}
```

Response pojo:

```
public class Result {
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;

    public Result(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

}
```

Anyone can help me please? why I get this error if the user already registered?
How Can I display the error {"message": "Failed! this user already registered!"} itself just like the success response?

Comment: Check your api for any error because if success works well means data is going to api and there should be no error in other cases as well

Comment: Have you check your data class or we call it POJO class?

Comment: @aryanknp The api works find in postman, so should change the status code return by API from 400 to 200 too? is this the problem or what

Comment: Yes I checked it and it works good for the success registration and should return same json structure in failed registration because previous existing but it's not work in this case
@XVallerie

Comment: can you post your retrofit sign up version?

Comment: @XVallerie I posted it check it please

Answer (score 0):

Actually the status code "**400**" is not an error code and because of that, you can create handling for that. I don't know if it'll work for you but as per your post, I think it's just the way you handle the response. Hope It'll help you :D

For example :

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, retrofit2.Response<Result> response) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    try {
                        if(response.body()!=null) {
               Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Welcome to our Apps", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else if (response.errorBody() != null && response.code() == 400){
                           Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, response.body(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            // If you want to add other handler
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    showCustomDialog2(response.errorBody().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, response.errorBody().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ERROR : ", t.getMessage());
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

But, if you have access to editing the server-side, I suggest you add a new field for the status code so that it'll make your app easier to check your user data so that your response JSON will look like this :

```
{
    "status": "400",
    "message": "Failed to sign up, user already exist !!"
}
```